# Can I use UIActivityViewController to share on Facebook ?

Tags: facebook, ios6, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am trying to use UIActivityViewController to share on facebook. 
When I am using the

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
NSArray* dataToShare = @[@"test",image];
UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =
[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll];
```

I can't see the "Share on Facebook" icon although I didn't exclude "UIActivityTypePostToFacebook". isn't there a predefined UIActivity for facebook ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: if you want only facebook icon to share:

```
-(IBAction)shareButtonPressed:(id)sender { NSLog(@"shareButton pressed");

NSString *texttoshare = _txt;
UIImage *imagetoshare = _img;
NSArray *activityItems = @[texttoshare, imagetoshare];    
UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

//in the list of excluded activity type insert any other kind of activitytypes you want to exclude

Answer (score 9):

you must be logged in your iphone settings:
Settings -> facebook

Comment: Yeah for me, I was trying it on my simulator the whole time. When I switched to iPhone everything was there.