# How to get only action button share facebook from UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, facebook, popup, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a case follows:

- In app, i create a UIButton, when click will show a popup share facebook like UIActivityViewController. But i don't known get popup share facebook from UIActivityViewController. I need help everybody.

THANK YOU SO MUCH !!!

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a UIActivityViewController and specify the items you wish to share:

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    NSString *textToShare = @"Put text here";
    UIImage *imageToShare = _img;
    NSArray *itemsToShare = @[textToShare, imageToShare];

    UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:itemsToShare applicationActivities:nil];
    [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

If you wish to exclude any [activity types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UIActivity_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Built_in_Activity_Types) you can do so by adding:

```
// add an array of activity types to exclude
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeMail, UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToTwitter, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo];
```

before presenting the activityViewController.

Also, to see the "share on Facebook" option, you need to be logged in to Facebook on the device, as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15188840/can-i-use-uiactivityviewcontroller-to-share-on-facebook).

///

**Option 2 - without UIActivityController**

If you do not want to use the Activity Controller, but instead just directly open the iOS social sharing dialog, you can do that by importing the `Social` framework and then using the [Social Compose View Controller](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/) (`SLComposeViewController`)

```
// import Social framework
#import <Social/Social.h>    

// check if there is an account for Facebook
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])    
{

    SLComposeViewController *fbController=[SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];

    // set up a completion handler (optional)   
    SLComposeViewControllerCompletionHandler __block completionHandler=^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result){

        [fbController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

        switch(result){
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
            default:
                break;
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                break;
    }};

    [fbController addImage:imageToPost];
    [fbController setInitialText:textToPost];
    [fbController addURL:urlToPost];
    [fbController setCompletionHandler:completionHandler];
    [self presentViewController:fbController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But, i look some app, i see button share facebook when click only show popup facebook share of activityViewController, not show activityViewController. So... have you other way ? .. :(

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a direct sharing option using the Social framework. Guess I misunderstood, what you were trying to accomplish. Hope this helps.